# Armazenar links banco de dados

Tags: php

Eu trabalho com url amigaveis.

Todas as requisições do meu site, passa sempre pelo `index.php`

Lá, eu queria pegar a url completa que alguem esta requisitando e gravar numa tabela do banco.

Como eu tenho varios tipos de combinações diferente (regras) no meu `htaccess`, pode vir urls assim:

```
www.site.com.br/news/111
www.site.com.br/produto/111
www.site.com.br/como-funciona/
www.site.com.br/news/carros/ford/11
```

Ou seja, existe uma infinita e extensa lista de regras.

Alguem pode me ajudar em como via PHP pegar essas url, e ir gravando numa tabela?

Comment: Tente isso:  $dominio= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
 $url = "http://" . $dominio. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; echo $url;

Comment: Teste e veja se atende. Coloque dentro de uma página qualquer.

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o exemplo abaixo:

```
function getUrlAtual() {
    $url = '';
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"])) {
        if ($_SERVER ["HTTPS"] == "on") {
            $url = 'https://';
        } else {
            $url = 'http://';
        }
    } else {
        $url = 'http://';
    }

    $url .= "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    return $url;
}

echo getUrlAtual();
```

Caso não queira salvar o protocolo, basta fazer assim:

```
echo "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Answer (score 1):

Aproveitando o código do @AllanAndrade:

```
<?php
function getUrlAtual() {
    $url = '';
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"])) {
        if ($_SERVER ["HTTPS"] == "on") {
            $url = 'https://';
        } else {
            $url = 'http://';
        }
    } else {
        $url = 'http://';
    }

    $url .= $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
    return $url;
}

$requisitado = getUrlAtual();

$username = 'root';
$password = 'root';

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=meuBancoDeDados', $username, $password);

$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO tabela (url) VALUE ("'.$requisitado.'")');
$stmt->execute();
?>
```